# Can I apply multiple CSS styles to Javascript `console.log` arguments?

Tags: javascript, css

Javascript's `console.log` allows me to apply CSS styles to the first argument like so:

```
console.log("%chey hey we're the monkees!", "font-weight: bold; color: fuchsia")
```

... which is awesome. But it doesn't play well with multiple log arguments.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
console.log(`%c${timestamp}`, "color: #999", `%c${tags}`, "background-color: #bbb", message)
// doesn't work; second format code is not interpreted
```

Is there any way to apply multiple format codes to multiple `console.log` arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed. You only need to add a second `%c` and then another `console.log` parameter in the same way as the first.

Example:

```
console.log(
  `%cMy first styles / %cMy second styles`,
  "font-size:24px",
  "font-size:12px;;"
);
```

So in your example, you should have the timestamp and tags in the same first parameter, and the next two parameters should be the independent styles, and finally your message:

```
console.log(`%c${timestamp} %c${tags}`, "background-color: #bbb","color: #999", message)
```